# Force invalidate of Windows Phone user control

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a User Control in Windows Phone XAML application, and I'm trying to restore a state after application is resuming from tombstone. During this state restore I'm changing `Foreground` brush of a `TextBlock` inside this control.

```
textBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red); //for example
```

The problem is that the foreground doesn't really change when I do this in `OnNavigatedTo` method. I'm using exactly the same code during normal workflow (after `Tap` event on something) and the foreground color changes.

When I check the `Foreground` value in the debugger, it's really changed, but the control doesn't repaint itself.

Is there a way to force the `TextBlock` to repaint itself? I could call `Invalidate()` in Windows Forms app, but I'm lost here.

Comment: Have you tried InvalidateVisual() ?

Comment: There is no InvalidateVisual I can find, I don't think it's in Windows Phone

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that Foreground changes as it should, but somehow I ended up with overlapping TextBlocks, my code changed the Foreground for the one in the bottom layer, and I could still TextBlock above it with unchanged Foreground. My bad.